# Improving accuracy of an n-body motion

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to solve the n-body problem with Newton's law of motion and gravitation in order to get the velocity distribution.

I've tried using RK4 and then the leapfrog algorithm while softening the potential and yet I can't get results that are accurate enough, since if two bodies come too close by the numbers go way up and the energy goes to a huge number so it is not preserved anymore, making the distrubtion useless.

The only trick that seems to work is reducing the timesteps. This, however, comes with a huge runtime price.

I'm looking for ways to improve my code so the energy will be preserved and the program runtime will be reasonable.
The relevant segment is: (Please notice: all masses are equal, G is set to 1, and I need to integrate large time intervals with the largest timestep possible to get good results. the variable e in the code is the potential softener and is set 0.005)

If you have suggestions for good values for the timestep/e/ other constants as well it will be highly appreciated.

```
for i=1:(length(t)-1)

for a1=1:n
    for a2=1:n
        if a1~=a2
     r(a1,a2)=sqrt((qstar(a1,i)-qstar(a2,i))^2+(qstar(a1+n,i)-qstar(a2+n,i))^2+(qstar(a1+2*n,i)-qstar(a2+2*n,i))^2); %Distances

     b(a1,a2)=1/(r(a1,a2)+e)^3; %Force component

     PE(1,i)=PE(1,i)+1/r(a1,a2); %Potential Energy

         A2(a1,a1)=A2(a1,a1)-b(a1,a2);      %Forming the ODE Matrix
         A2(a1,a2)=b(a1,a2);
         A3(a1,a1+n)=A3(a1,a1+n)-b(a1,a2);
         A3(a1,a2+n)=b(a1,a2);
         A4(a1,a1+2*n)=A4(a1,a1+2*n)-b(a1,a2);
         A4(a1,a2+2*n)=b(a1,a2);

        end
    end
    V(a1,i)=sqrt((qstar(a1+3*n,i))^2+(qstar(a1+4*n,i))^2+(qstar(a1+5*n,i))^2); %velocity
end

   PE(1,i)=0.5*PE(1,i);

    A=vertcat(A1,A2,A3,A4);

    if i==1 %RK4
         k1 = A*qstar(:,i);  % Approx for y gives approx for deriv
  y1 = qstar(:,i)+k1*h/2;      % Intermediate value (using k1)

  k2 = A*y1;        % Approx deriv at intermediate value.
  y2 = qstar(:,i)+k2*h/2;      % Intermediate value (using k2)

  k3 = A*y2;        % Another approx deriv at intermediate value.
  y3 = qstar(:,i)+k3*h;        % Endpoint value (using k3)

  k4 = A*y3;        % Approx deriv at endpoint value.

  qstar(:,i+1) = qstar(:,i) + (k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)*h/6; % Approx soln
    else %leapfrog

  acce = A*qstar;  % Approx for accelaration
  qstar(:,i+1) = qstar(:,i-1) + 2*h*acce(:,i); % Approx soln
    end



        A2=zeros(n,6*n);
        A3=zeros(n,6*n);
        A4=zeros(n,6*n);

        end
```

I formed a matrix which when multiplied by qstar will give the laws of motion.
qstar stores both the location and the velocity, it goes like this:

x1,x2,...,xn,y1,...,yn,z1,...,zn,px1,...,pxn,py1,...,pyn,pz1,...pzn

only vertical. x1 symbols the location on the x axis of body number 1, and py4 for example symbols the momentum of body 4 along the y axis.

Comment: I don't really understand what your question is.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to improve the code runtime, whether it's by using another algorithm or little tweaks that you can help me with, with this code.

Comment: Are you familiar with adaptive-stepsize RK methods? You might have luck with that.

Comment: Yes, I've tried RK4 with adaptive-stepsize prior to the Leapfrog, no success there.

Comment: @Talco You'll need to expand on "no success". Was the estimated error bound for the stepsize always within reason? If not, why not?

Comment: @Sneftel No success means that the runtime was unbearable. There's a delicate game between the stepsize and the runtime, what currently is happening with the code is that the stepsize needed for the energy to be preserved is too extreme runtime-wise, even if we set it for only for small distances.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [symplectic integrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator), since it will approximately preserve the energy.

Comment: Leapfrog is Verlet to my understanding, so it should preserve the energy.